# How to integrate swagger into karate framework

Tags: swagger, karate

I want to integrate swagger with karate framework. I searched on the internet for the resources but I couldn't find any resource to integrate swagger with karate framework. Is there any way to integrate swagger with karate?

Comment: This will be a commercial tool, work in progress and you can look at this set of demos: https://github.com/ptrthomas/karate-oas-demo - if interested, reach out at https://www.karatelabs.io/studio